# SQL Server database security reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We are running SQL Server 2008 R2, few db’s with sensitive data, and different user roles.

So far I have been using SSMS audit feature to check for changes but I would also like to make some kind of report (weekly, monthly), if there is an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to SQL Server Audit, it has no built in reports, but if you saved the output into .sqlaudit files, you can read them using the fn_get_audit_file function

```
SELECT event_time , session_server_principal_name AS UserName , 
server_instance_name AS ServerName, database_name , object_name , statement 
FROM 
sys.fn_get_audit_file('D:\AUDITs\AuditDatabaseAW2012*.sqlaudit',DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

Using the **WHERE** clause for the *event_time* column with adequate condition will return the events for the specific time period

There are also third party tools that provide built-in reports, but selecting the right one depends on what changes you want to track and what kind of reports to generate

[ApexSQL Comply](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_comply.aspx) is a SQL Server auditing tool with a wide range of possibilities for auditing access, changes, and security on SQL Server instances, databases, and objects. It audits queries, DDL and DML operations, security events (authentication changes, permissions changes, and attempted logins), stored procedures, and functions. ApexSQL Comply saves captured information in a centralized auditing repository, and provides comprehensive reports

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*